# Ввод текста на HTML+Python

Tags: python, html, бот

У меня есть сайт на html. Также есть бот на pythom (вопрос-ответ с помощью print и input). Я хочу что бы через строку ввода на сайте,  текст из python (print или input) импортировался на сайт и писал ответ ниже, что бы было видно что пользователь написал и что мне ответил python. Есть ли какие то способы это реализовать?
Это должно выглядеть на подобии ботов из aiproject.ru Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Да, это очень легко. Нужно только чутка помучаться с `websokets`. Постараюсь сейчас из своих недр выудить +- рабочий пример на python, js и html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий код:

### Python

```
# WS Сервер (базовый пример)

import asyncio # Библиотека стандартной архитектуры асинхронного ввода - вывода в Python
import websockets
import pymysql
import json
import datetime

async def hello(websocket, path): # На стороне сервера websocket выполняет 
    # сопрограмму обработчика hello один раз для каждого соединения
    ask = await websocket.recv()
    ask = json.loads(ask)
    if ask["comm"] == 'get':
        print('Я ПОЛУЧИЛ КОМАНДУ!')
        await websocket.send('Ну, здорова, Странник!')

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
# Закрывает соединение после возврата
# async/await -(специальный синтаксис для работы с промисами)
# Промис- это объект,
# представляющий возможное завершение передачи или сбой асинхронной операции
# В Python async гарантирует, что функция вернет промис и обернет в него не промисы.
```

### HTML + JS(Всё в одном)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebSocket demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="get">Получить данные</button>
        <script>
            function get_readers(){
                var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8765/"),
                    messages = document.createElement('ul');
                    ws.onopen = function () {
                        let data = {
                            comm: 'get'
                        };

                        let json = JSON.stringify(data);
                        ws.send(json);
                    };
                ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                    var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
                        message = document.createElement('li'),
                        content = document.createTextNode(event.data);
                    message.appendChild(content);
                    messages.appendChild(message);
                };
                document.body.appendChild(messages);
            };
            document.getElementById("get").addEventListener("click", get_readers)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот рабочий пример. Вам остаётся только допилить `input` в HTML и передавать через `JSON`(там есть строка `get` в html, туда добавить пункт `output` и в python тоже через `JSON` выудить ввод, а дальше `if else`).

PS Появятся вопросы - пишите в ВК(ссылку можно найти в аккаунте ;))

Comment: Привет, вк пишет нет страницы)) Спасибо за статью) начал недавно изучать HTML и CSS.... и интересует связка с питоном (пишу дектопку на eel)  однако не могу понять как вывести данные в тег title, Причем скрипт получает и обновляет данные каждые 0,3 секунды. Может есть какие варианты по реализации ??

Comment: @xxxHEKETOSxxx, спасибо что сказал про ВК) Я просто id поменял, а тут инфу забыл обновить XD

Comment: @xxxHEKETOSxxx, напиши мне сюда: https://vk.com/dgdays